# Custom UIbutton default color Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to create a custom UIButton class like so, but I don't see the backGround color updated, also it doesn't show as the default color in the inspector either. I want it to be so that I can change all the colors of those instances from this class file without having to set it manually for each button.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class PrimaryButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var borderwidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
      didSet {
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderwidth
      }
   }
   @IBInspectable var cornerradius: CGFloat = 4.0 {
      didSet {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerradius
      }}
   }
    @IBInspectable var backgroundcolor: UIColor = UIColor.red {
      didSet {
        self.layer.backgroundColor = backgroundcolor.cgColor
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate , do you need to apply same settings to all buttons in IB ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan I just need to apply the settings to all buttons of this class.

Comment: look of whether the below answer is what you need

Comment: @Sh_Khan That works yeah, although I wish I was able to view it in inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create custom class like this then set it for any button in IB

```
@IBDesignable class MyNewButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        shared()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        shared()
    }

   override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
       super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
       shared()
   }
   func shared() {

        //TODO: add any custom settings here
        self.layer.cornerRadius = value
        self.layer.borderWidth = value
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
   }

}
```

Comment: Yo!! Thanks so much! You're amazing